# How do I use a Dropdown 'Entries' Field Type in a Front End Form

Tags: entries-field

I have an [Entries field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields) that I need to have as a drop-down field in my front-end form. The code below is displaying the correct options, although after selecting and submitting the form, the `tbdDesignerUrl`-field is not populated with the selection in the entry.
It shows as nothing selected. (`tbdDesignerUrl` is the name of the Entires field I am trying to populate through the form and `entry.designerUrl` is the field I am using to select the entry in the options.)

```twig
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('designers') %}
  <select name="fields[tbdDesignerUrl]" id="fields[tbdDesignerUrl]">
    {% for entry in entries %}
     <option value="{{ entry.designerUrl }}">{{ entry.designerUrl }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

Thanks for any help you can give! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply put, an [Entries field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields) is an array containing entry ids, and your form needs to send it that way.

Just replace `name="fields[tbdDesignerUrl]"` with `name="fields[tbdDesignerUrl][]"`. That way the [value gets submitted as an array](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

Also replace `value="{{ entry.designerUrl }}"` with `value="{{ entry.id }}"`, since we need the submitted value to be an [entry id](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#id).